# Can't use \usemintedstyle and \setstyle for multiple languages

Tags: luatex, minted, bugs

I have the latest version of minted in which I can define color styles for each language (since v2.0, now it's v2.6), but apperently, when using `minted` environment for multiple languages the code breaks with "FancyVerb Error:". I use lualatex (through latexmk).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usemintedstyle[ini]{vs}
\usemintedstyle[bash]{vim}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{ini}
# comment
\end{minted}

% I can use minted for the same language many times just fine
\begin{minted}{ini}
# comment
\end{minted}

% latex gives error when this is uncommented (due to multiple "\usemintedstyle")
% \begin{minted}{bash}
% # comment
% \end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I get no error if I remove `cache=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [egreg said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660966/cant-use-usemintedstyle-and-setstyle-for-multiple-languages/660988#comment1644407_660966), removing `cache=false` fixed the problem! I wonder why... (I thought this package would function in the exact same way without cache)

P.S. I reverted to `[cachedir=.cache]` and it still works.